# How to create an Installer for Odoo to Linux/Windows (any version)

Tags: python, installation, odoo, odoo-8

My goal is to install Odoo to my computer with minimal steps or lets say less command in terminal

Any idea? suggestion?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you looking for this? https://github.com/aschenkels-ictstudio/odoo-install-scripts

Comment: This isn't a good question for stackoverflow

Comment: I sugest you tu use vagrant + virtuallbox, I can send you my configuraton, at least for learning prupose

Comment: hi @danidee, installation script is one of the option, but is there any other way rather than that?

Answer (score 1):

Using [Vagrant](https://www.vagrantup.com/) you can try this https://github.com/efirvida/odoo9-vagrant. Just install Vagrant and VirtualBox, and run `vagrant up` inside the folder. Then after a while, you have the latest odoo-v9  running on a virtual machine you can access by http://localhost:8069 and you can put your own modules in the local addon folder to be used in the odoo.

Just test it, and any issue let me know.

Comment: Hi @efirvida, thanks for your suggestion, its an option for me to use Vagrant or Docker. 

But i am aiming to create an installer of Odoo, like an executable, so my client will not thinking any setup/configuration.

But if there is no other way, I will choose Docker rather than Vagrant.